# Multiple Mongos on one server

Tags: mongodb

I'm not talking about [sharding](https://serverfault.com/questions/242618/mongodb-sharding-on-single-linux-machine). We had a *testing* server (linux) and there is already one `mongo` which belongs to another project/subteam. Is it possible to run **multiple, isolated instances** of `mongodb` on one machine? How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by specifying different port numbers and data directories for the other instances of `mongod`, and then specifying the new port number in the client.

For example:

```
./mongod --dbpath /foo/bar/otherpath --port some_other_port
```

You can [also change](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes) the shard server and config server port numbers if you need to.

Comment: Is it possible to specify this within mongodb.conf? Or would I have to create a script to do that? (on *nix)

Comment: @Justin, you can certainly specify these options within a config file - see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration.  But then you still need to pass different config files to the different instances.

Comment: Thanks @dsolimano, I've got two scripts in rc.d for two instances of Mongo. I've specified different paths for the db, pid, logging and given them different ports to listen on. It's also being forked, and when the second script runs it fails as mongo is already running (the first instance). So I guess my real question was (I I haven't had much luck finding this on the web) is can you have two forked instances running at the same time?  Thanks

Comment: @Justin, I think this probably rises to the level of a new question, perhaps you should ask it on this site?  It sounds like there is something about the way you're starting Mongo that is causing a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The steps I've taken are:

1. Copy conf file /etc/mongod.conf to mongod2.conf and also to mongod3.conf
2. Edit conf files to have different ports and different database paths
3. Copy init.d start script /etc/init.d/mongod to mongod2 and also to mongod3
4. Copy binary mongod /usr/bin/mongod to /usr/bin/mongod2 and also to /usr/bin/mongod3
5. Edit init.d start scripts and changed the following:

   CONFIGFILE="/etc/mongod2.conf" (mongod3.conf, respectively)

   ....

   mongod=${MONGOD-/usr/bin/mongod2} (mongod3, respectively)

Replaced /var/lock/subsys/mongod with /var/lock/subsys/mongod2 (mongod3, respectively) wherever I found it.

Resist the temptation to replace mongod.lock with mongod2.lock (or to mongod3.lock, respectively). They are in different folders (database folders are different) and won't conflict.

Now I can

```
service mongod start|stop|status

service mongod2 start|stop|status

service mongod3 start|stop|status
```

and also

```
mongo --port <port_number>
```

for each mongo instance (remember the port settings from the conf files)

I am not aware of any side effect of renaming the mongod binary..

Hope this helps.

[Later edit]
To start the instances automatically, just ln -s /etc/init.d/mongod2 /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S86mongod and ln -s /etc/init.d/mongod3 /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S87mongod :)

Comment: Ah Nice one! did exactly the same without much luck before because I didn't think we should also duplicate the mongod executable itself. All good now.

Comment: In my case, using `Ubuntu 16.01`, there were no `init.d` scripts. Can you provide `init.d` script content?